# Right to left Marquee of text in wpf where width of text block is greater then Window without flickering

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I am using following code for animation(right to left marquee):-

```
    private void RightToLeftMarquee(TextBlock tb)
    {
        doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.From = -tb.Width;
        doubleAnimation.To = TickerCanvas.Width;
        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever; 
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Right)"));
        sb.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        sb.Begin(tb,true);
    }
```

This code moves the textblock fine when width of textblock is less then the canvas but when the textblock width is greater then canvas width the marquee flickers.

Answer (score 0):

The flickering you're seeing is probably due to ClearType sub-pixel positioning. You have a few options, but the animation will not look as smooth after applying them:

- `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"`

  This turns on the newer WPF 4.0 ClearType algorithm, which will make the text look crisper.
- `UseLayoutRounding="True"`

  Ensures that WPF aligns everything to the device pixels (no more blurry borders, images, etc.)

I *always* use both of these settings at the root elements of any app (i.e. all `Window`s) because it generally improves the way the application looks.

Comment: hi Eli Arbel. Thanks for your answer. I would like to know how to set TextFormattingMode in wpf as I could not find the said property for TextOptions.